# How to insert movie in Palin Tex?

Tags: plain-tex, media9

How to insert movie in Palin Tex?

```
% Plain TeX
\input media9.sty

\includemedia[addresource=cube.mp4,
flashvars={source=cube.mp4&autoPlay=true &loop=true},passcontext 
]{\includegraphics[height=0.45\linewidth]{cubeposter}}{VPlayer9.swf}}

\bye
```